# Cannot get the response error from useSWR error property

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch-api, swr

I am using Next.js, and trying a little testing of SWR before integrating it into my app. So this below is just a faker.api test to see how it goes and get familiar with it.

Everything is working pretty well, but for some reason I can't seem to be able to get the error back, my console log does not print anything in the console.

```js
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import { useState } from 'react'
import useSWR, { SWRConfig } from 'swr'
import UseBooks from '../Hooks/UseBooks'

type HomeProps = NextPage & {
  serverData: any
}

const fetcher = (url:string) => fetch(url).then(r => r.json()) 

const Home = ({serverData}: HomeProps) => {
const [shouldFetch, setShouldFetch] = useState(false)
const {data, error} = useSWR(
  `https://fakerapi.it/api/v1/ompanies?_quantity=10`,
  fetcher,
  {
    fallbackData: serverData,
    onError: (error, key)=> {
     console.log(error)
    }
  })

const  [booksData, booksError]  = UseBooks(shouldFetch, 'https://fakerapi.it/api/v1/books?_quantity=10')
const handleClick = () => {
  setShouldFetch(true)
}

  return (
    <div>
        {JSON.stringify(booksData)}
        <ul>
          {data?.data?.map(el => (
            <li key={el.id}>{el.name}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>next</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export async function getServerSideProps(){
  const res = await fetch(`https://fakerapi.it/api/v1/companies?_quantity=10`)
  const serverData= await res.json()
  return{ props:{serverData}}
}

export default Home
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected behaviour because [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) doesn't actually reject when the request returns a non-2xx response, it only does so when a network error occurs. If you log `data` to the console, you'll notice that it contains the error response body: `{ status: "Not found", code: 404, total: 0 }`.

You can use the `fetch` response's `ok` property to determine whether the request returned a 2xx response, and if not throw an error yourself.

```js
const fetcher = (url: string) => fetch(url).then(r => {
    if (!r.ok) {
        throw new Error('Something went wrong with the request')
    }
    return r.json()
})
```

Alternatively, you can use `axios` instead - as it will throw an error when a non-2xx response is returned.

```js
const fetcher = (url: string) => axios(url).then((r) => r.data);
```

Comment: thank you ! i was not getting a consle print out because i was console logging the wrong event..but still, using Axios error object i can't get the error status back, can't get the 404 status out of this object : https://ibb.co/9G3H0N0
In this object, the status shows a code 0, instead of a 404...

Comment: @julBayonna That's because you're actually getting a network error, the request isn't getting fulfilled. Can you get the expected result when making the request from Postman?

Comment: Oh right...thanks ! i will try postman